# Add variables using Pentaho "Run" options

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a need to build a system that fetches data from an Amazon pgdb3 and provide a constant that is used later in the transformation, which is "S_ID" here.[image: S_ID here]

This is my transformation and it is giving me errors if I try to use the variable as `${S_ID}` in the "Add constants" step as shown.[image: Add Constants]

What do I need to do in order to make the transformation succeed?[image: Transformation]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the *Add constants* step has been modified in later versions, but in my 8.2 version of PDI it doesn't allow the use of variables in the Value.

Use the *Get variables* step instead.